# Can I create a page link from a slide in bxslider

Tags: hyperlink, bxslider

I want to create links to pages in my website when a user clicks on a slideshow picture generated with bxSlider (which is excellent in every other way)

Can this be done? How? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/1240

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
<li>
  <div class="item-img2">
    <a style="background-image: url('picture.jpg');"  href="http://www.google.com"></a>
  </div>
</li>
```

And in CSS

```
.item-img2 {
width:980px;
height:500px;
}

.item-img2 a {
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
width:980px;
height:500px;
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an a href... for exemple:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/slide001.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/slide002.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul>
```